# How to express 4-digit number while using Xpath in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

The purpose is to scrape a website using Scrapy.  The things I want to get are each between div with unique 4-digit numeric id as the following:

```
<div id="3456" ...> Item 1 </div>
<div id="5643" ...> Item 2 </div>
<div id="8767" ...> Item 3 </div>
```

I need to know how to generically define the 4-digit number in the following command, so I can go to each Item for scraping.

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="4-digit-number-description"]'):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Scrapy, you can use [regular expressions inside the XPath expressions](http:////div[http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions), very convenient:

```
response.xpath('//div[re:test(@id, "\d{4}")]')
```

Comment: It works as a charm! Thanks!  A related question: if I also want to get each "id", do you have any suggestions?  I tried "sel.xpath('/id/()')" or "sel.xpath('/id/test()')", but didn't work.